# Проблема(-ы) с 'Виселицей'

Tags: python

Решил написать что-то на подобие 'Виселицы'. Помимо проблемы с отсутствием отображения самой виселицы также почему-то программа не проходит дальше смены регистра введённой буквы. Ограниченные познания в программировании не дают мне понять в чём проблема, поэтому помогите, пожалуйста.

```
from random import choice, randint
words = ('компьютер', 'тетрадь', 'монитор', 'чашка', 'часы', 'игла', 
'ножницы', 'ручка', 'карандаш', 'линейка')
descriptions = ('Устройство, спсобное выполнять операцию или ряд операций', 
'Тонкая брошюра для письма', 'Стеклянные сосуд для напитков', 'Устройство 
для определения времени', 'Острая швейная...', 'Металлические ножи для резки 
бумаги', 'Гелевое или масляное устройство для начертания знаков', 
'Инструмент для начертания знаков с графитным стержнем внутри', 'Устройство 
для измерения длинны чётко отведеннного промежутка пространства')

def fine(i):
      print(process[i])
      return i+1

process = ('''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         
         |      
         |         
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |      
         |      
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |         |
         |         |
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|
         |         |
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |        /
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |        / \
         |       -----
         |       |   |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |        / \
         |      
        ---

      ''')


game = True
while game == True:
      print('1 - Играть')
      print('2 - Выйти')
      result = input('Введите 1/2.\n')
      if game == 1:
          k = randint(0, 8)
          print('Угадайте:')
          print(descriptions[k])
          word = words[k]
          word_inp = '_'*len(word)
      for c in word_inp:
          print(c, end = ' ')
      print(word_inp)
      i = 0
      while word!=word_inp and i<len(process):
                char = input('Ваша буква: ')
                if len(char)>1:
                    char = char[0:1]
                char = char.lower()
                if char is word:
                    if not(char is word_inp):
                        print('Yep!')
                        for j in range(len(word)):
                            if word[j] == char:
                                word_inp = word[0:j]+char+word[j+1:]
                            print(word_inp)
                    else:
                        i = fine(i)
      else:
          i = fine(i)
if word == word_inp:
      print('You win.')
else:
      print('You lose.')
      print(word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю зачем вам первый цикл `while` потому что здесь можно обойтись и обычным `if`ом (вы же просто спрашиваете у пользователя нажмите либо то либо это).
Потом когда вы проверяете букву на ее наличие в слове вы используете `is`(логический перевод *"является"*) вместо `in` (логический перевод *"в"*).

Как исправить чтобы выводило слово по буквам как вам надо(корректно) я к сожалению не могу сказать, но чтобы воспроизводилась сама *виселица* описал ниже

```
print('1 - Играть')
print('2 - Выйти')
result = int(input('Введите 1/2.\n'))
if result == 1:
    k = randint(0, 8)
    print('Угадайте:')
    print(descriptions[k])
    word = words[k]
    word_inp = '_'*len(word)
for c in word_inp:
    print(c, end=' ')
print(word_inp)
i = 0
while word != word_inp and i < len(process):
    char = input('Ваша буква: ')
    if len(char) > 1:
        char = char[0:1]
    char = char.lower()
    if char in word:
        if not(char in word_inp):
            print('Yep!')
    else:
        i = fine(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы удобно было отображать угаданные буквы, можно сохранить позиции, на которых находятся буквы в искомом слове:

```
target_word = random.choice(list(words))
chars = {c: [] for c in set(target_word)}  # char -> positions in the word
for position, char in enumerate(target_word):
    chars[char].append(position)
```

где `words = {'electroencephalograph': 'description...', 'another word': 'description...'}`.

Начав с `display_chars = ['_'] * len(target_word)` и получив, к примеру, букву `'e'`, легко обновить `display_chars`:

```
print(words[target_word])  # print description
while '_' in display_chars:
    guess = input('Guess a char: ')  # 'e'  
    if guess in chars:  # found char
        for i in chars[guess]:
            display_chars[i] = guess  
        print(*display_chars)  # e _ e _ _ _ _ e _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
    else:  # not found: misses.append(guess)
        try:
            print(next(gallows))
        except StopIteration:
            sys.exit('You lose.')
print("You win!")
```

где `gallows = iter(process)`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import json
import random
from browser import document, html, alert


def print_(*args, sep=' '):
    text = sep.join(map(str, args))
    print(text)
    alert(text)
    document <= html.PRE(html.CODE(text))
    
def play_game(words):
    gallows = iter(['''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         
         |      
         |         
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |      
         |      
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |         |
         |         |
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|
         |         |
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |        /
         |
         |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |        / \
         |       -----
         |       |   |
        ---

      ''',
      '''
         -----------
         |         |
         |        --- 
         |         O
         |        /|\
         |         |
         |        / \
         |      
        ---

    '''])
    
    target_word = random.choice(list(words))
    chars = {c: [] for c in set(target_word)}  # char -> positions in the word
    for position, char in enumerate(target_word):
        chars[char].append(position)
    print_(words[target_word])  # print description

    display_chars = ['_'] * len(target_word)    
    while '_' in display_chars:
        guess = input('Guess a char: ')  # 'e'  
        if guess in chars:  # found char
            for i in chars[guess]:
                display_chars[i] = guess  
            print_(*display_chars)  # e _ e _ _ _ _ e _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
        else:  # not found: misses.append(guess)
            try:
                print_(next(gallows))
            except StopIteration:
                print_('You lose.')
                break
    else: # guessed the whole word
        print_("You win!")

@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event=None):
    play_game(json.loads(document["json"].value))    
on_click('dummy on start')
</script><label for="json">Слова: </label><textarea id="json">{"компьютер": "Устройство, способное выполнять операцию или ряд операций", "тетрадь": "Тонкая брошюра для письма", "чашка": "Стеклянные сосуд для напитков", "часы": "Устройство для определения времени", "игла": "Острая швейная...", "ножницы": "Металлические ножи для резки бумаги", "ручка": "Гелевое или масляное устройство для начертания знаков", "карандаш": "Инструмент для начертания знаков с графитным стержнем внутри"}</textarea><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```